# In jsp how to do onload with a condition?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I know how to do a onload, and I know in jsp how to test a condition, but how to do a :

```
<body onload="clearCache()">
```

Only when :

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null
```

Comment: Could you not output a `data` attribute to the body element and have some Javascript look for that value. If it's there, run the `clearCache()` function, and if not, do nothing? It's pretty archaic to have code run via JavaScript inlined in HTML these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of generating the body tag based on the condition.

Not elegant but let's try this :

```
<% 
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null)
{
 <body onload="clearCache()">
}
else
{
<body>
}

%>
```

then rest of the body markup continues. Would it help ?

Answer (score 0):

Include the `if` statement at the top of your `clearCache` function:

```
function clearCache() {
   if (request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null)
   {
      //Do stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: I think we should assume that the `request.getSession....` is Java, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

something on the lines of:

```
<body data-sticky="<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("stickyCarrier") != null %>" onload="clearCache()">
```

And in the javascript (using jQuery)

```
function clearCache() {
  if($(body).data('sticky') !== false) {
    //Do stuff here
  }
}
```